# Pyomo uses __round__ method for NoneType

Tags: python, optimization, model, modeling, pyomo

I am implementing a simple optimization problem using Pyomo.

```
import pyomo
import pyomo.opt
import pyomo.environ as pe
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,1,1,15])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
c = 10
P_res = 5

model = pe.ConcreteModel(name = "base optimizer")

model.M = pe.RangeSet(1,2)
model.T = pe.RangeSet(1,P_res)
model.state = pe.RangeSet(1,4)

st_lb = np.array((-1.22,) * P_res)
st_ub = np.array((1.22,) * P_res)
th_lb = np.array((0,) * P_res)
th_ub = np.array((1.0,) * P_res)

def th_b(model, i):
    return (th_lb[i-1], th_ub[i-1])
model.th = pe.Var(model.T, domain=pe.Reals, bounds = th_b)
model.x = pe.Var(model.T, model.state, domain = pe.Reals)
model.z_predicate = pe.Var(model.T, model.M, domain=pe.Binary)

def obj_rule(model):
    return model.th[P_res]**2
model.OBJ = pe.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense = pe.minimize)

def init_state(model,s):
    return model.x[1,s]  == a[s-1]
def dynamic_1(model,t):
    if t == P_res:
        return pe.Constraint.Skip
    return model.x[t+1,1] == model.x[t,1] + model.x[t,4] * pe.cos(model.x[t,3])
def dynamic_2(model,t):
    if t == P_res:
        return pe.Constraint.Skip
    return model.x[t+1,2] == model.x[t,2] + model.x[t,4] * pe.sin(model.x[t,3])
def dynamic_3(model,t):
    if t == P_res:
        return pe.Constraint.Skip
    return model.x[t+1,4] == model.x[t,4] + model.th[t]
    
model.InitConstraint = pe.Constraint(model.state, rule = init_state)
model.DynConstraint1 = pe.Constraint(model.T, rule=dynamic_1) 
model.DynConstraint2 = pe.Constraint(model.T, rule=dynamic_2)
model.DynConstraint3 = pe.Constraint(model.T, rule=dynamic_3)

def binary_constraint(model,t):
    return  model.z_predicate[t,1] <= 1 
model.BiConstraint = pe.Constraint(model.T,rule=binary_constraint)
 
solver = pyomo.opt.SolverFactory('mindtpy')
results = solver.solve(model, mip_solver='gurobi', nlp_solver='ipopt', tee=True)
```

However, I got the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d441aab4faca> in <module>
     56 
     57 solver = pyomo.opt.SolverFactory('mindtpy')
---> 58 results = solver.solve(model, mip_solver='gurobi', nlp_solver='ipopt', tee=True)
     59 
     60 # solver = pyomo.opt.SolverFactory('ipopt')

c:\users\hongk\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\MindtPy.py in solve(self, model, **kwds)
    169             # Algorithm main loop
    170             with time_code(solve_data.timing, 'main loop'):
--> 171                 MindtPy_iteration_loop(solve_data, config)
    172             if solve_data.best_solution_found is not None:
    173                 # Update values in original model

c:\users\hongk\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\iterate.py in MindtPy_iteration_loop(solve_data, config)
     99                     fixed_nlp, fixed_nlp_result, solve_data, config)
    100 
--> 101         if algorithm_should_terminate(solve_data, config, check_cycling=True):
    102             last_iter_cuts = False
    103             break

c:\users\hongk\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\iterate.py in algorithm_should_terminate(solve_data, config, check_cycling)
    307     if check_cycling:
    308         if config.cycling_check or config.use_tabu_list:
--> 309             solve_data.curr_int_sol = get_integer_solution(solve_data.mip)
    310             if config.cycling_check and solve_data.mip_iter >= 1:
    311                 if solve_data.curr_int_sol in set(solve_data.integer_list):

c:\users\hongk\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\util.py in get_integer_solution(model, string_zero)
    550                     temp.append(int(round(var.value)))
    551             else:
--> 552                 temp.append(int(round(var.value)))
    553     return tuple(temp)
    554 

TypeError: type NoneType doesn't define __round__ method
```

I tried to comment out the model.BiConstraint and replace the last two lines as

```
solver = pyomo.opt.SolverFactory('ipopt')
results = solver.solve(model, tee=True)
```

and it worked out fine. So I guess the error comes from the model.BiConstraint.

Does anyone knows why Pyomo does this? I cannot find the reason from any Pyomo materials.

My configuration.
Python 3.6.13 :: Anaconda, Inc.
Pyomo 6.1.2 (CPython 3.6.13 on Windows 10)
gurobi             9.1.1
ipopt              3.11.1
mindtpy            0.1

Answer (score 0):

There's something goofy going on with your solver setup....  I'm not familiar with that type of setup using `mindpy`

This works just fine:

```
solver = pe.SolverFactory('ipopt')
results = solver.solve(model)
print(results)
model.display()
```

Further update...
Your original problem appears to be related to the fact that part of you `z_predicate` variable are *not referenced at all* in your model, specifically when M=2.  That is causing them to be "stale" which I believe is causing `mindpy` to barf.  If you change your constraint to :

```
model.BiConstraint = pe.Constraint(model.T,model.M,rule=binary_constraint)
```

`mindpy` does it's thing just fine.  Also note that this constraint is not active in your model as `z_predicate` is unused.

Comment: But Ipopt gives the warning  `==> Warning: Treating 5 binary and 0 integer variables as continuous, and the binary variables are not 0 or 1.  Ipopt is an NLP solver and cannot solve an MINLP.

Comment: OK.  I din't look at the problem that closely...  When I tweaked the constraint such that it wasn't stale and `mindpy` did its thing, it sent it to gurobi solver, which may be what you want.  It puked on me there because my gurobi license is long expired.  Try nailing down your `BiConstraint` as I mention above and give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnSmith

The problem is that `mindtpy` is trying to apply the `round()` function to a `None` value. Now, the `None` value comes, effectively from the following:

You're modeling `model.z_predicate = pe.Var(model.T, model.M, domain=pe.Binary)`
and `model.M = pe.RangeSet(1,2)` the problem is that you're not assigning any value to `model.z_predicate[model.T, 2]` since in your constraint you're only constraining `model.z_predicate[model.T, 1]` in the `binary_constraint`

You can do a couple of thing with that:

1. Delete the unused index of `model.M`:

   ```
     model.M = pe.RangeSet(1)
   ```
2. Using an initial value for `model.z_predicate`:

   ```
    model.z_predicate = pe.Var(model.T, model.M, domain=pe.Binary, initialize=0)
   ```

In both ways, you're avoiding the `NoneType` round problem and getting a solution. In my case (I don't know if is ok) is:

```
INFO: ---Starting MindtPy---
INFO: Original model has 21 constraints (8 nonlinear) and 0 disjunctions, with
28 variables, of which 5 are binary, 0 are integer, and 23 are continuous.
INFO: Objective is nonlinear. Moving it to constraint set.
INFO: rNLP is the initial strategy being used.
INFO: NLP 1: Solve relaxed integrality
INFO: NLP 1: OBJ: 0.0  LB: -inf  UB: inf
INFO: ---MindtPy Master Iteration 0---
INFO: MIP 1: Solve master problem.
INFO: MIP 1: OBJ: 0.0  LB: 0.0  UB: inf
INFO: NLP 2: Solve subproblem for fixed binaries.
INFO: NLP 2: OBJ: 0.0  LB: 0.0  UB: 0.0
INFO: MindtPy exiting on bound convergence. LB: 0.0 + (tol 0.0001) >= UB: 0.0

>>>model.OBJ.expr()
1.286551594275684e-09
```